# LEFT JOIN unrelated entity to root table in JPA Criteria builder

Tags: java, jpa, left-join, entitymanager, criteria-api

I have got 2 tables `TABLE_A` & `TABLE_B`. I have got 2 entity classes for these 2 tables named `TableA` & `TableB`.

TableA has got an attribute which is actually a foreign key, is ID of TableB. But this relation is not there at table level as well as entity class level.

Which means that these two tables are unrelated with respect to entity manager.

Now I want to generate a jpa query like below

```
select  
   tablea.name, tableb.name 
   from TableA tablea left join TableB tableb on 
   tablea.tablebId=tableb.pkId
```

Basically Table_A is my main table.

Here is what I have trie, this is doing cross join

```
       String rootClassNameWithPackage = "TableA";
        String fkClassNameWithPackage = "TableB";

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery = null;
        Root<?> rootTable = null;
        Root<?> fkTable = null;

        try {
            criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);
            rootTable = criteriaQuery != null ? criteriaQuery.from(Class.forName(rootClassNameWithPackage)) : null;

            fkTable = criteriaQuery != null ? criteriaQuery.from(Class.forName(fkClassNameWithPackage)) : null;

            List<Predicate> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();

            Predicate predicateSearchFk = criteriaBuilder.equal(rootTable.get("tablebId"), fkTable.get("pkid"));

            criteriaList.add(predicateSearchFk);
            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        final TypedQuery<?> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        query.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        return query.getResultList();
```

As mentioned earlier, this is doing cross join. We want to left join. Unfortunately we cant change the entity classes to add the FK relationships.

Comment: Did you try to use explicit join type with https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/criteria/From/join_String_JoinType

Comment: [This](https://thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) is *the only way* you can make it work (assuming you're using Hibernate). What you're asking is impossible using vanilla JPA

Comment: There is always an option to use native query or techs built on top of native query like https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA